# ECDSA_bainpoolP512 vs ECDSA Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP) / ECDSA_nistP384 vs ECDSA_secP384 vs ECDSA_P384

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, ecc

During the creation of a certificate request through the Windows Certificate Store, at the options for the private key, there are the following options for choosing a KSP:

> *ECDSA_brainpoolP512,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

> *ECDSA,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

What are their differences?

In addition:
The windows certificate store, during the creation of a request, gives the following options for the private key:

> *ECDSA_nistP384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

> *ECDSA_secP384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

> *ECDSA_P384,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider (KSP)*

As far as the standards go, these are all the same curve. What are their differences in the KSP?

Answer (score -1):

The difference is in curve algorithms/implementations. 2nd option defaults to NIST_P512 algorithm, while first uses Brainpool algorithm. NIST-based versions are often faster than brainpool.

Comment: There does not exist a Nist_P512 named curve. They chose 521 on purpose, because 2^521-1 happens to be a prime.